# Validate given date is yesterday date

Tags: lua, kong

I'm new to lua programming and I'm working on license verification in kong.

I want verify the expiry date with current date.

How do I verify in lua script.

Comment: I don't like needlessly bitching about the rules, but in this case I really think you should have shown a bit more effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

I made this function for you

```
function verifyExpiration(expirationDate)
  local expirationTime = os.time(expirationDate)
  local currentTime = os.time()
  local result = false

  if (expirationTime < currentTime) then 
    result = true
  end

  return result
end
```

It will return:
  true if expired 
 ,false if have not expired

and here is some example of how it works:

```
> expT = {year=2018, month=1, day=1}
> verifyExpiration(expT)
> print(verifyExpiration(expT))
true
> expT = {year=2019, month=1, day=1}
> print(verifyExpiration(expT))
false
```

Comment: Returning 1 or 0 is certainly not the lua way of doing things. This isn't C; we have boolean values.

Comment: no problem, i will change true for true and 0 with false

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Returns true if the given time is in the past.
function dateExpired(expirationTime)
  return os.difftime(os.time(), expirationTime) < 0
end
```

Note that `expirationTime` is a time value as returned by `os.time()` or `os.date()`. If you have your date saved as a table, you can simply feed it through `os.time()` first: `dateExpired(os.time{year=2018, month=5, day=22})`